# Angular 7 Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<{}>'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx

I can not figure it out why i got this error

```
  getByURL(url: string): any {
    return this.apiService.get(url).pipe(map(data => data));
  }

  getByNextPage(): Observable<any> {
    const url = 'url';
    this.getByURL(url).pipe(
      expand(data => {
        console.log(data);
      })
    );
  }
```

I got this error at line that has expand(data => ... . I want to use expand() so i can recursive the call for the next api.

```
Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<{}>'
```

Any hint would be really appreciate. Thanks

Comment: Try adding a return statement to getByNextPage() b/c is not returning anything,

Comment: @artemisian Thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56398014/recursive-using-expand-and-concatmap-in-angular-7. I have another question here which related to this one. Not sure if you can take a quick look. I got stuck there. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are using expand() operator badly. If you check documentation, the expand() operator has to return an Observable and you are not returning nothing.

Even though you return "data" variable the error will still persist because that rule.

[Check this documentation](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/expand.html)

Answer (score 2):

You need check data type of data variable and return data in your method.

```
getByNextPage(): Observable<any> {
    const url = 'url';
    this.getByURL(url).pipe(
      expand(data => {
        console.log(data);
        return data;
      })
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you help me to take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56398014/recursive-using-expand-and-concatmap-in-angular-7. Its related to this question but i have know clue why.

Answer (score 2):

```
expand(data => {
  console.log(data);
})
```

Your function does not return anything, hence the void. You need to return an observable.