# Recursive using expand() and concatMap() in Angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have following API list below:

```
1. https://www.something.com/?filter=something

Result: 
{ 
  id: 12
  previous: null
  next: https://www.something.com/?filter=something&page=2
  data: ...
}

2. https://www.something.com/?filter=something&page=2

Result: 
{ 
  id: 13
  previous: https://www.something.com/?filter=something
  next: https://www.something.com/?filter=something&page=3
  data: ...
}

3. https://www.something.com/?filter=something&page=3

Result: 
{ 
  id: 14
  previous: https://www.something.com/?filter=something&page=2
  next: null
  data: ...
}
```

I want to loop through all of the urls after getting the data back of each API call, check if the   next variable is null. If it is not null, it will keep continue going. while it's going through, the data of each API call will be concat and return to output.

This is what i have been trying so far

```
 getByURL(url: string): any {
    return this.apiService.get(url).pipe(map(data => data));
  }

  getData(): Observable<any> {
    const url = 'https://www.something.com/?filter=something';
    return this.getByURL(url).pipe(
      expand(({ data }) => {
        if (!data.next) return this.getByURL(data.next);
        else return empty();
      }),
      concatMap(({ content }) => {
        return of(content.data);
      })
    );
  }
```

But i got undefined result, i have struggled it for several day. Thanks

**UPDATED**

I put my code here in stackblitz: 
I have 3 api call :

```
http://5cf15627c936cb001450bd0a.mockapi.io/users
http://5cf15627c936cb001450bd0a.mockapi.io/users2
http://5cf15627c936cb001450bd0a.mockapi.io/users3
```

I want to gather all of the data after each requests. Please see the console to see the output. i always get undefined. Thanks

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rai6az?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Why cant you make the Json object an array and loop through it ?

Comment: I have thought about that, and i was thinking, why dont we just use the key: next after each requests. Thats what i am trying todo.

Comment: My original solution is that: i generated all of the url myself, and loop through it and gather the data results.

Comment: Also your API should not send  previous: null when its null just don't send previous

Comment: i am using Django Rest Framework for my back-end API. Those are what i got from the framework.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 Http, Observables and recursive requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40529232/angular-2-http-observables-and-recursive-requests)

Comment: @RezaRahmati Thanks. I have seen that post. and trying to make it work in my own problem. But i couldn't. I feel like i am missing something, somewhere. Just cant figure it out. or may be i am doing it totally wrong.

Comment: @daniel8x the code you posted here is different, also if you can create a stackblitz for it we can help you better

Comment: @RezaRahmati Thanks. I have updated my question. you can see the stackblitz link there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed your code as below ([fixed stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-recursive-http-call))

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getByPageNext()
      .subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
      });
  }

  get(url: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient
      .get(url)
      .pipe(catchError(this.formatErrors));
  }

  formatErrors(error: any) {
    console.error('error', error);
    return throwError(error.error);
  }

  getByURL(url: string): any {
    return this.get(url);
  }

  getByPageNext(): Observable<any> {
    const url = 'https://5cf15627c936cb001450bd0a.mockapi.io/users2';
    return this.getByURL(url)
      .pipe(
        expand((response: Array<any>) => {
          if (response && response.length && response[0].next) {
              return this.getByURL(response[0].next);
          }
          else {
            return empty()
          }
        }),
        map(obj => obj[0]), 
        reduce((acc, x: any) => acc.concat([x.data]), []),
      );
  }
```

so it will concat all data as array and recursive calling http works fine.

The only problem is when calling 'https://5cf15627c936cb001450bd0a.mockapi.io/users' the next url is `http` not `https` which will result in HttpError -> ProgressEvent.

So I started form 'https://5cf15627c936cb001450bd0a.mockapi.io/users2' and rest is working fine. So after you changed the backend to fix the next link, then change it back to your original request.

The other point was your result from api comes back as an array not an object, this is why I accesses `result[0]`

The other point was your condition to return empty() was vice versa